# Variable introduction technique for elementary algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was just reading about problem 22 from book 6 of Diophantus's *Arithmetica*.  He solves these simultaneous equations using an unusual technique:

$$P_{1}P_{2}=14$$
$$P_{1}+P_{2}+\sqrt{P_{1}^2 + P_{2}^2}=12$$

He reduces the number of variables from two to one by setting $P_{1}=1/x$ and $P_{2}=14x$.  The equations become much easier to solve at that point.

What is that technique called, and where might I find more information about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique is called *elimination*.

Im your example, you eliminate $P_2$ by setting $P_2=14/P_1$ from the first equation.

Comment: That's different, superficially at least, from what Diophantus did.  Are you saying that it's not really different enough to be considered a separate technique?

Comment: @sam.bishop, I think it's just superficially different.

Comment: It's also a change of variables.  Replacing $P_2$ by $x = P_2 /14$.

Comment: @lhf, I think you're right.  The book I'm reading (The Story of \sqrt {-1}) describes the approach as a clever time saver, but it just seems to be an standard technique written in an unusual way.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

(*Too long for a comment*.)  FWIW another common approach to solve such equations is to note that they are symmetric in $P_1, P_2\,$, and therefore can be expressed in terms of the elementary symmetric functions $A=P_1+P_2$ and $B=P_1P_2\,$. The equations become:

$$
\begin{cases}
B = 14 \\
A + \sqrt{A^2-2B} = 12
\end{cases}
$$

This immediately gives $A+\sqrt{A^2-28}=12 \implies A = \frac{43}{6}\,$, then $P_1, P_2$ are the roots of the quadratic $x^2-Ax+B=0 \iff 6x^2-43 x +84 = 0\,$ (*or*, as Diophantus would have written it $6x^2 +84 = 43 x$ since the ancient Greeks didn't work in negative numbers).